# How does back propagation in CNN works for pre-trained embedding in text classification

Tags: conv-neural-network, word2vec, pre-trained-model

How do the loss function works in case of pretrained word2vec embeddings as the weights are not updated during training.Then how do the backward pass works and what does it update for prediction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loss is a calculation of the probability outputs and actual classes, this calculation is not dependent on the training status of any subsequent layers. By status I mean *trainable==True* or *trainable==False*.

Back-propagation of the loss is used in combination with the learning rate to **adjust the weights of a layer only if the status is *trainable==True***. The error can still pass through these layers if there are trainable layers in between non-trainable layers. Any layers in your model that are "trainable" will update after each training step.

When using Word2Vec, the weights are imported into the embedding layer and many times are "frozen" so as not to update while the rest of the parameters are trained. Towards the end of this process, however, sometimes unfreezing these weights can allow for better results.